# Polya’s Urn and conditional probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, martingales

**Setting:**

At time $0$, an urn contains $1$ black ball and $1$ white ball. At each time $n ≥ 1$ a ball is chosen uniformly at random from the urn and is replaced together with a new ball of the same colour. Just after time $n$, there are therefore $n + 2$ balls in the urn, of which $B_n + 1$ are black, where $B_n$ is the number of black balls chosen by time $n$. We let $F_n = σ(B_1,...,B_n)$ for $n ≥ 1$ and $F_0 = \{∅,Ω\}$.

I want to show:
$\mathbb{P}(B_{n+1}=b | \mathcal{F}_n)=\frac{B_n +1}{n+2}\chi_{B_n = b-1}+ \frac{n+1-B_n}{n+2}\chi_{B_n = b} $

I think that this comes from:
$\mathbb{P}(B_{n+1}=b | \mathcal{F}_n)=\mathbb{P}(B_{n+1}=b | B_{n}=b-1)\chi_{B_n = b-1}+ \mathbb{P}(B_{n+1}=b | B_{n}=b)\chi_{B_n = b} $
This of course intuitively makes sense. But why is it true formally?

I tried to state a general version of this:

Let $X$ be a real, discrete random variable taking values $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. If there is a partition $\{F_i\}_i \subset \mathcal{F}$ of $\Omega$, we have:
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}(\chi_{X=x_i} | \mathcal{F})=\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}(\chi_{X=x_i} | F_j) \chi_{F_j}
\end{equation}

I tried to show this via the unique property $\forall B \in \mathcal{F}: | \mathbb{E}(\chi_B \chi_{X=x_i})= \mathbb{E}(\chi_B \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}(\chi_{X=x_i} | F_j) \chi_{F_j}) $. But I failed, can someone maybe tell me if my general statement is true or where the property above comes from. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general statement is false, which can be easily seen if you take $\{\Omega\}$ as the partition. The right side then reduces to $\mathbb E(\chi_{X=x_i}|\Omega)\chi_{\Omega} = \mathbb E[\chi_{X=x_i}]$ and it's obviously not true that every random variable is equal to its expectation.

In fact, you can show that your right side is just $\mathbb E(\chi_{X=x_i}|F_1,\dots, F_n)$, conditioning on the $\sigma$ algebra generated by the partition, so the statement you want to show and "intuitively makes sense" in your question is actually
$$
   \mathbb P(B_{n+1}=b|\mathcal F_n) = \mathbb P(B_{n+1}=b|B_n).
$$
You want to show that $B_{n+1}$ only depends on $B_n$, and not on the rest of $\mathcal F_n$. This property actually has a name: It is called the *Markov property* and what fulfils this property is called a *Markov chain*. But actually it is easier to proof the original statement. Just note that *according to the text*, the ball chosen in step $n+1$ only depends on the number of balls in the urn. This means
$$
   \mathbb P(B_{n+1}-B_{n} = 1 |\mathcal F_n) = \frac{B_n+1}{n+2}
$$
a.s. and we can get the statement as
\begin{align}
   \mathbb P(B_{n+1} = b |\mathcal F_n) &= \mathbb P(B_n=b, B_{n+1}-B_{n} = 0 |\mathcal F_n)
+\mathbb P(B_n=b-1, B_{n+1}-B_{n} = 1 |\mathcal F_n)
\\ &= \chi_{B_n=b}\mathbb P(B_{n+1}-B_{n} = 0 |\mathcal F_n)
+\chi_{B_n=b-1}\mathbb P(B_{n+1}-B_{n} = 1 |\mathcal F_n)
\\&= \frac{B_n+1}{n+2}\chi_{B_n=b} + \frac{n+1-B_n}{n+2}\chi_{B_n=b-1}.
\end{align}
In the second step, we used the fact that for some $\sigma$ algebra $\mathcal F$, a $\mathcal F$-measurable variable $Y$ can be factored out as $\mathbb E(XY|\mathcal F) = Y\mathbb E(X|\mathcal F)$ a.s.

**Edit:** If we now turn back to the Markov property, we see that the right side of the equation only depends on $B_n$, so $\mathbb E(B_{n+1}| \mathcal F_n)$ is $\sigma(B_n)$-measurable and thus equal to $\mathbb E(B_{n+1}| B_n)$. If you can't see why $\sigma(B_n)$-measurability implies that, see that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(B_{n+1}=b|B_n) &= \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E(B_{n+1}=b|\mathcal F_n)|B_n\right] \\
&= \mathbb E\left[\frac{B_n+1}{n+2}\chi_{B_n=b} + \frac{n+1-B_n}{n+2}\chi_{B_n=b-1} | B_n \right] \\
&= \frac{B_n+1}{n+2}\chi_{B_n=b} + \frac{n+1-B_n}{n+2}\chi_{B_n=b-1} \\
&= \mathbb E(B_{n+1}=b|B_n).
\end{align}

**Edit 2:** That the ball drawn in step $n$ does only depend on $B_n$ in $\mathcal F_n$ is only written *in the text* or rather only implied. We assume that a uniformly random ball is chosen, that means, all balls have the same probability to be picked, and that this is not dependent on the balls picked before ($\mathcal F_n$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand why $\mathbb{P}(B_{n+1}-B_n=1|B_n = b)=\frac{b+1}{n+2}$ is true. But could you maybe explain why we also have: $\mathbb{P}(B_{n+1}-B_n=1|\mathcal{F}_n)=\frac{B_n+1}{n+2}$?

Comment: I think what I’m asking for is, why does this „Markov property“ hold?